# the_title function for Wordpress doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I'm convering a html one page to wordpress but I can't seem to get the title for each section to return the right vaule.

This code is form page.php which displays the one page:

```
<?php
  // Template Name: One Page Layout
  get_header();
?>

<?php

  // Main Loop
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  // GET HEADER
  get_template_part( 'front-header');

  // PROMOTION SECTION
  get_template_part( 'front');

  // LATEST WORK
  get_template_part( 'lwork');

  // LATEST POSTS
  get_template_part( 'lpost');

  // ABOUT ME
  get_template_part( 'about');

  // CONTACT
  get_template_part( 'contact');

  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();

  get_footer();
?>
```

Here is the title I want to show (lpost.php):

```
<!-- section heading -->
<section class="section-heading">
 <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
 </section>
```

What am I missing out on??

Answer (score 0):

You need to put loop above the section

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<section class="section-heading">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</section>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: i hope you have added get_posts ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts )code in head of lpost.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
<?php
  query_posts(array('post_type' => 'post'));
  // Main Loop
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code : get_title()

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<section class="section-heading">
<h2><?php get_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</section>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```